# Math on operators in differential equations.

Tags: self-learning, differential-operators

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6T43tNbbQg&list=PL5zYzNir_uFKkGSCPxO8GREGdJkl1tzNh&index=2) Michael Penn video and it lead me to try a couple of things and they ended up not working.

Specifically, he solves the following problem like so

Starting with $y'' = y$

$y'' - y = 0$

$\left( (\frac{d}{dx})^2 - I \right)y = 0$

And because $I$ is the identity operator, then $I = I^2$, so

$\left( (\frac{d}{dx})^2 - I^2 \right)y = 0$

$\left( (\frac{d}{dx}) - I \right) \left( (\frac{d}{dx}) + I \right)y = 0$

Then he sets

$\left( (\frac{d}{dx}) + I \right)y = Y$

So now we have

$\left( (\frac{d}{dx}) - I \right)Y = 0$

Which we can solve for $Y = Ae^x$

And to summarize, we can then use this in $\left( (\frac{d}{dx}) + I \right)y = Ae^x$ and solve for $y$ using an integrating factor. It's all neat stuff. I've never seen this kind of problem solved this way though and I found it fascinating. But I'm clearly very new to this idea. So I'm curious about why it can't be used in the following way.

$y'' + fy' + gy = 0$

$\left( (\frac{d}{dx})^2 + f \frac{d}{dx} + g \right)y = 0$

$\left( (\frac{d}{dx})^2 + f \frac{d}{dx} + g \right) = 0$

Then using pythag

$\frac{d}{dx} = - \frac{f}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{f^2}{4} - g}$

Putting the y back in

$\frac{dy}{dx} = y\left( - \frac{f}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{f^2}{4} - g} \right)$

At this point, it's pretty straight forward to solve for $y$.

$y = Ae^{\int{ \left( - \frac{f}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{f^2}{4} - g}\right)}dx}$

Now this doesn't work, and frankly, I wasn't really expecting it to work, mostly curious about what would pop out. But the question I have is why doesn't this work. How does operator algebra work? Please enlighten me?

Comment: You're right but I'm having trouble understanding the full notation and how to implement it. I don't quite follow what you wrote or where it fits in with what I wrote.

Comment: Maybe as a remark: Why don't you just do the Laplace trafo? All what you are doing just looks like pretending to be in the time domain even though having implicitly transferred the system into frequency domain, and all the problems you have seem to stem from the fact that you don't do the transformation explicitly...

Comment: The process you described sounds both really cool and really useful but I’ve never heard of doing it this way. How would one accomplish this?

Comment: The Laplace trafo is pretty simple: $d/dt x$ becomes $s X - x(0)$, i.e. differential equations become algebraic ones if they are linear (and time invariant). So, whenever you see somebody writing $(d^2/dt^2-I)=(d/dt-I)(d/dt+I)$, all they are really saying is that $(s+1)(s-1)=s^2-1$ which is really elementary and absolutely nothing new.

Comment: That's cool. I went through university and took most of their calculus classes, but I struggled with most of the Laplace stuff. That's fascinating though, I'm going to go back and look deeper into it, thank you.

Comment: be warned, there are two different approaches to the topic. You want the one were you never have to calculate an integral and instead work with transformation tables (and even use them only once in a while).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, factorization of differential operators is a valid technique in solving differentials equations, but the way you did it only works in the case where $f,g$ are constants, so that everything commutes.

Let's assume you have a differential operator $L$ which can be factored as $L=AB$. Then, the problem $Ly=ABy=0$ can be decomposed into the sub-problems $Ay=0$ and $By=0$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute, as in Michael Penn's video.

If those differential operators do not commute, you will have to solve $Ay=0$ to begin with and afterwards the inhomogeneous problem $By = y_A$, where $y_A$ is the general solution to the first equation $Ay=0$ $-$ so that the general solution satisfies $Ly = ABy = Ay_A = 0$.

In your second example, you could take :
$$
\begin{array}{l}
   L = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + f(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + g(x) \\\\
   A = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + \alpha(x) \\\\
   B = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + \beta(x)
\end{array}
$$
so that
$$
Ly = ABy = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + \alpha\right) \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + \beta\right) y = y'' + (\alpha+\beta)y' + (\alpha\beta+\beta')y
$$
hence
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
   f = \alpha+\beta \\
   g = \alpha\beta+\beta'
\end{array}
\right.
\verb+ +\Rightarrow\verb+ +
\beta'= g-\alpha\beta = g - f\beta + \beta^2
$$
which is a quite complicatede first-order nonlinear ODE for $\beta$ depending on the given functions $f,g$.

Once you have found $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (if possible), you still need to solve the new problems :
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
   \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + \alpha\right)y_A = 0 \\
   \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + \beta\right)y = y_A
\end{array}
\right.
$$
But those are standard first-order linear ODE.

Comment: I've spent a fair bit of time working on this. Turns out, a solution to this is $y = e^{\int \beta dx}$. There's also an equivalent second order ODE, almost a partner one that looks like $Y'' - fY' + \left( g - f' \right)y = 0$. Turns out you can actually solve for a solution to $\beta$ and it's a complex infinity. When treated as a constant, this gives the correct solution where $\beta = \frac{f}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{f^2}{2} - g}$. The whole problem is screwy, but I think solving it will require another degree of math similar to how the derivative changed finding slopes.

Comment: Yes, one solution is indeed $y_1=\exp(-\int\beta\,\mathrm{d}x)$, which is the homogeneous solution to the 2nd equation, where the inhomogeneous solution is $y_2=\left(C+\int\frac{y_A}{y_1}\mathrm{d}x\right)y_1$, where $y_A=\exp(-\int\alpha\,\mathrm{d}x)$ and $C$ is a constant. But the hard part is finding $\beta$ from $\beta'=\beta^2-f\beta+g$ in the first place for non-constant $f,g$.